# How to load a .txt file into matlab ignoring -nan(ind) values or changing them to zeros

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

I'm struggling to create MATLAB code which will upload a `.txt` file which contains -`nan(ind)` in some cells. I've tried many of the functions like `textscan` and `dlmread` but none of them have worked so far.

These `-nan(ind)` cells only occur in the first two and last two rows. How can I:

1. upload the text and change all `-nan(ind)` cells to zero, or
2. only load the numerical portion of the matrix, i.e the matrix minus the first 2 and last 2 rows.

The matrix will always have 18 columns, but the length will vary. The .txt file is called `segmental_force_moments.txt`

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all NaNs with zeros without looping through the whole matrix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439582/replacing-all-nans-with-zeros-without-looping-through-the-whole-matrix)

Comment: `textscan` is a really rich function. You can set `TreatAsEmpty` with `-nan(ind)`  and `EmptyValue` with `0`.

Comment: Tried ... *how*? Because if you read `doc textscan` or `doc dlmread` you'll see that it's actually pretty straightforward to do what you need to do...

Comment: dlmread doesn't seem to work as i have string data. I've read the document for textscan and my code below doesn't seem to be working fid = fopen('segmental_forces_moments.txt');
in = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f','HeaderLines',2);
fclose(fid); As you can tell I'm new to this